Deploying Laravel application to production - files/app not deployed
I have a standard Laravel application which I have developed locally using Laravel Herd, that I am trying to deploy to my production environment. I am using Portainer, and I only have access to the Portainer ui.
I have the following files in my app's root folder:
Dockerfile:
# Use the official PHP image with FPM
FROM php:8.3-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libpq-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql gd

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/html

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Change the owner of the application directory to www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

EXPOSE 8010

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: athena
    container_name: athena-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    pull_policy: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - athena-network
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: athena-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT:-80}:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - athena-network

  pgsql:
    image: 'postgres:15'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
    environment:
      PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
      POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
      POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
    volumes:
      - 'sail-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
      - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/pgsql/create-testing-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sql'
    networks:
      - athena-network
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - pg_isready
        - '-q'
        - '-d'
        - '${DB_DATABASE}'
        - '-U'
        - '${DB_USERNAME}'
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
networks:
  athena-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  sail-pgsql:
    driver: local

In Portainer, I simply create a stack which pulls from my GitHub repo's docker-compose.yml file.
The stack deploys succesfully, but when I try to access the webserver on port 8010, I am not able to connect (error: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED").
When I go to the app container's console in Portainer and check the file content, I don't see any of my Laravel app files?
/var/www/html# ls
docker  vendor

